# Was King Saul's body cremated after he died?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, samuel-shmuel-book-of

I read in the book 1 of Shmuel ([31:12](http://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.31.12))

> וַיָּק֜וּמוּ כָּל־אִ֣ישׁ חַיִל֮ וַיֵּלְכ֣וּ כָל־הַלַּיְלָה֒
>   וַיִּקְח֞וּ אֶת־גְּוִיַּ֣ת שָׁא֗וּל וְאֵת֙ גְּוִיֹּ֣ת בָּנָ֔יו
>   מֵחוֹמַ֖ת בֵּ֣ית שָׁ֑ן וַיָּבֹ֣אוּ יָבֵ֔שָׁה וַיִּשְׂרְפ֥וּ אֹתָ֖ם
>   שָֽׁם׃
>
> all their stalwart men set out and marched all night; they removed the
>   bodies of Saul and his sons from the wall of Beth-shan and came to
>   Jabesh and burned them there.

**What does this mean?** Was King Saul's body cremated after he died?

Comment: The question could be greatly improved if you add why you think cremation is an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I Samuel 31:11-12**

> *The inhabitants of Jabesh-gilead heard about him - about what the Philistines had done to Saul - and all the daring men arose and went throughout the night, and took the remains of Saul and the remains of his sons from the wall of Beth-shan, and came back to Jabesh. They burned them there.*
>
> **31:12.** According to most commentators, they burned Saul's belongings, in accord with the dictum that no one may use a king's possessions. *Radak* suggests that the bodies had become decomposed and infested, so the people burned the flesh, leaving the bones for burial.

[All quotations from the Stone Edition Tanach from ArtScroll-Mesorah.]

It appears that the common opinion is that they burned Saul's belongings, and that's what is meant by "and they burned them there."

See [Avodah Zarah 11a](http://www.themercava.com/app/#books/metanav/17352) for more concerning the custom of burning a king's possessions, although the above passukim are not referenced. (Thanks to DonielF for finding that for us.)